# How to solve SSL error in python while requesting and while doing pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl-certificate

I was trying a simple python program using request but i was getting bad handshake.
here is my code-

```
import requests
requests.get("https://google.com")
```

and here is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 488, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1647, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 494, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\Software\SOFTWARE PRACTICE\pyhton stock market\practice.py", line 16, in <module>
    requests.get("https://google.com")
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "path to python\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

I even get SSL error while doing pip,error is as follows
pip install SciPy

```
Collecting SciPy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certif
icate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certif
icate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certif
icate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certif
icate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certif
icate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/scipy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/: There was a problem confir
ming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max re
tries exceeded with url: /simple/scipy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationE
rror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
 certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SciPy (from versions:
)
No matching distribution found for SciPy
```

but i use following code to successfully install any libraries from pip

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Please help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: Are you behind a company proxy?

Comment: @TheFool No, own network

Comment: What you are doing there is normally for working with proxies. Something on your system seems to be messed up.

Comment: Maybe Stack Overflow is not the right corner for this question. It seems to be networking related.

Comment: @rahul What type of system are you using? Are you on Mac by chance?

Comment: @NoahBroyles I'm on windows 8.1

Comment: @TheFool But everything on my laptop working great but how to know the problem is from where python or system, is there any code to execute with python to confirm is it not related or related to python ?

Comment: Its just telling you its not happy with the cert. This has usually nothing to do with python. One thing comes to mind, let's encrypt had recently issue with their certs. And they are widely used.

Comment: @TheFool so do you have any idea what should i do because i'm not getting any route to look further